# I can't find the QT Designer even though it is installed

Tags: python, pyqt5, oserror

I downloaded the QT-Designer with 'pip install pyqt5-tools' and no error message came up. However, in the folder 'C:\ANACONDA\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5_tools' where I saved my python and the 'pyqt5-tools' object is stored I cannot find the 'designer.exe'. In all the YouTube toturials I have watched the 'designer.exe' should be found. I have installed the Python version 'Python 3.9.7' with ANACONDA.

Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 16:59:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Comment: You need to provide more details, you said that you "downloaded", but in the title you mention installing. Please explain more precisely what you did, and also specify the OS and python version.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I can solve your problem since you said

> 'C:\ANACONDA\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5_tools' where I saved my python and the 'pyqt5-tools' object is stored

I installed `pyqt5-tools` via Conda environment named `Python3.10`. here is the path where I can find `designer.exe` file:
`C:\Users\Shayan\Anaconda3\envs\Python3.10\Library\bin`

So **if** you installed `pyqt5-tools` via a Conda environment, you can find `designer.exe` in a path like this:
`C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Anaconda3\envs\<YOUR_ENVIRONMENT_NAME>\Library\bin`

Or you can search for `designer.exe` via the search option of windows!